# High average response time from HDD

Tags: hard-drive, sata

Specs:

- CPU: i5 2500k
- GPU: 6870 2GB
- Memory: 4gbx2
- MOBO: Z68XP-UD3
- HDD: ST31000524AS, WDC WD10EAVS
- OS: Win 10 Tech Preview.
- Past OS: 7, 8, 8.1 (problems occured on all of these.)

**Problem:** So I have had an on going problem for quite some time now. I first noticed it when my computer performance in games (such as SW:TOR) had been going down. Textures taking longer to load, levels longer to load, etc. I figured it was just SW:TOR. But it had continued to get worse. It went from taking seconds to load a level, to taking upwards of 5 minutes. I first noticed that whenever this would happen, I would get a very high Hard Fault/sec. As I continued looking around, I noticed that I would get a very high average response time; which I've read that anything over 50 is a problem. I have seen numbers upwards of 100k MS. This happens more than just playing games. Starting windows I will reach 20k-80k, it will also happen randomly when nothing but my browser is running, reaching 400-6000+ ms. When installing something such as a game or program, the Average response time goes from 6k-30k. Opening a web page in chrome takes up to a minute, assuming it doesn't crash.

**Trouble shooting:** Replaced Ram.
Ran Seagate Tools from dos (all tests), HDD passed everything.
Ran the same tests from Linux, passed.
Replaced Sata Cable, slight improvement.
Zero'd HDDs, fresh installs, nothing.

I am including pictures of several HDTune scans of my drives. You will notice that they can be quite erratic.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf1al.jpg

The SMART results are included in that link as well now.

Comment: Normally long delays in HDD response is indicative of the drive having trouble reading some portion of the disk. Check the SMART data, particularly reallocated sectors count, seek error rate, spin retry count, and the various uncorrected error counts; what are those? Though normally that's a problem with a single drive, so your second drive test should have eliminated that variable. Maybe a glitch with the HDD controller circuitry or cabling? Try new SATA cables and verify that all power cabling is secure and your PSU is properly spec'd. Failing that, try different SATA ports. Hope this helps.

Comment: Here are the Health Status': https://i.imgur.com/EMCtRwM.png https://i.imgur.com/Lv1MkQa.png Everything looks ok. At least to me. 

I have already tried switching ports, but I can try again. Why not. I'm using two different cables, so I don't think that's the issue. It would seem odd that both of my cables would be faulty. My PSU seems to be fine as well, but what do you mean properly spec'd? Do you mean how much it's putting out?

Comment: Did you run Memetest with the new RAM in there? If it fails too then it's your motherboard.

Comment: Yes I did. Memory checked out ok.

Comment: I should add, that I originally tested this second HDD through USB 2.0, and it showed similar symptoms as well. But I chalked it up to being USB 2.0. 

I tested that with Win 8.1

Comment: I agree, that SMART data looks quite good. Those are both brand new disks? (I notice that they both have less than 100 power-on hours logged.) By properly spec'd PSU I do mean whether it is rated for the power draw of your system on the necessary [rails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply_unit_%28computer%29#Functions). Honestly the best I can think of at this point is to run a SMART extended self-test as well as a SMART conveyance test and see what comes out. There's either something wrong with both drives, or there's something wrong with your system somewhere other than the HDDs.

Comment: In general, please [edit] your post to incorporate information requested in comments, and use a comment to ping the person who asked for the specific information (`@` followed by their user name) to notify them of the edit. Also just edit the information in; don't bother with specific "EDIT:" tags. That helps keep the comments clean. Comments on Stack Exchange are supposed to be ephemeral, and can be deleted for almost any reason at all once they have served their purpose. Questions and answers remain.

Comment: Ok, sorry, that's what I thought you meant...but wanted to make sure. Yes, I have a 650w PSU. No, both drives are old. The WD drive is actually older than the ST3 drive. I have done an extended test, and everything checked out ok. 

Could the drives just be old, and while not throwing errors etc, just not performing well anymore? I'm not too familiar with how HDDs wear with time. If performance can degrade to this level, while SMART checking out and extended tests checking out ok.

Sure thing about the edits, my apologies.

Comment: No need to apologize, it takes a little while to get used to how we do things around these parts. The Q&A format is good for curating knowledge, however. Stick around a while and you'll get the hang of it soon enough; we all started out newcomers. As for the power-on hours, I misread; my apologies for that. A HDD shouldn't normally need several hundred milliseconds or more to complete a read, pretty much no matter its age. The only thing I can think of to try is to run a completely separate OS and try to read the files, to rule out software problems. Other than that, I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: I think I'll install a Linux distro on one of the drives, and see if it still performs poorly. I've ran Ubuntu off my 3.0 flash drive, and everything was great. But a flash drive isn't a HDD, so I'm not sure if that gives any useful information.

Comment: Either way it would be a useful data point.

Comment: Updated with results. Ordered a new sata cable as well, after that, guess it's just throw hard drive and mobo at it.

Comment: I was told not to Edit :/ It's also...not a wall of text. I can edit it more...but a wall of text doesn't have any formatting etc.

Comment: Who told you not to edit? Did you by chance misunderstand Michael Kjörling's editing advice?