# HDD long response times when trying to use it

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, windows-8.1

To preface this, I've already seen this 
[seemingly similar issue.](https://superuser.com/questions/848956/high-average-response-time-from-hdd)
Unfortunately nothing in there really helps lead me to a solution so I'm making my own question.

**To start, system specs are as follows:**

- **CPU** - i7 4790K
- **MB** - Asus Hero VI
- **SSD** - Crucial MX100 256GB (100GB of 120 used of the OS partition)
- **HDD** - Seagate Barracuda 3TB 7200 (One partition is 70% full)
- **RAM** - Crucial Ballistix Sport 8GB x1
- **OS** - Windows 8.1 Pro

My system isn't terribly old by any means - only three years old max, and I keep in the inside of my case and my fans pretty clean.

**My Issue**
The response times on my HDD are becoming longer, often jumping to a couple thousand MS when I attempt to do something with any of the data or programs stored on it.

While IDLE, my Disk Usage is minimal, 0-10% or so but mostly staying on 0%.

While running any programs, they will usually load very slowly if they don't fail to begin with.  Then they either stall constantly or eventually crash entirely.  I'm seeing a lot of "Wait for the program to respond."
If anything keeps running, the Disk usage caps out at 100% and stays there.

While booting, the process is greatly delayed.  Once the boot even failed but I haven't seen that happen again.

While shutting down, the process is stalled.

While running anything that is strictly located on my SSD, including things related to OS, there are absolutely no problems at all.

**What I've Tried**
I've error checked/ran optimizations of my SSD, HDD, and RAM already without finding any issues with any of them.

I've run a virus scan, returning no threats.

I've deleted some programs to free up space on my OS partition in case that was causing delays.

I've tried resets and applying updates as well.

**My Question**
What's wrong and what do I do now?  Is there something I can do to further pinpoint my issue?

Comment: To whoever voted down my issue, please understand how the SO community works and provide feedback as to why you did so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first to check internal status of your HDD by pull up [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) attributes.
You can use either command line tool from [smartmontool](https://sourceforge.net/projects/smartmontools/) or you can use GUI wrapper that calls [GSmartMonTools](http://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.net/home/index.php/Downloads).

When you pull up SMART status, check attributes 5, 196, 197, 198. (Meaning of all of these attributes described pretty well in the link above.)
If any of them has value greater than 0(zero) then your HDD is physically failing.

Comment: [SMART Error Log](http://i.imgur.com/K9IWnZW.png)  
[SMART Report](http://i.imgur.com/64ZJ3H7.png)  
I can't make much sense of it myself, but 5's threshold passes 0, and that seems to be the issue right?
If you can elaborate on what all of these means for my benefit of knowledge, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: based on the screenshot, the drive will fail soon. Buy a new drive and backup all data asap.

Comment: @magicandre1981 any advice on how to back it up?  It's pretty slow and I'm not sure how long I have, or how to treat my computer until I can get a new drive here in the next few days.

Comment: @Nol you should save your files as soon as possible !!! All important attributes are red so your disk will stop working completely pretty soon and you'll loose a lot of files. Always look at raw value of attributes I wrote in my answer

Comment: I appreciate the urgency, I went out and got a backup drive while I find a new HDD and extra SSD to toss into my rig.  Last thought: is there any way to salvage a dead HDD other than dominoes?

Comment: It depend what is exact issue with HDD, sometimes it's a control board, but more frequently it's mechanical problem. When there just a few remapped by firmware sectors it possible to force firmware to replace broken sectors and such drives will work for a long time(usually it happened when drive was stressed while it work), but it isn't a case with your hard drive, - too many already remapped sectors and more than thousand candidates to remap. HDD repair is very expensive, at least 10 times more than a new HDD. Usually people who lost very important data are ready to pay for such service.